# Google Webmasters NodeJs API Understanding Response

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-api-webmasters

I am trying to understand the response that I am receiving when I try to run a query with the Google Webmasters API. I am not getting an error as the console.log is returning `null`, but I receive `Not Found` for the `res` parameter, which makes it seem like something is off with the `params` object that I am passing to the query method. When I look at the [webmaster github file](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/webmasters/v3.js), it appears that I am passing the right fields in the right order, but something must be off. Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to debug this further or where something is clearly off in with my object key-value pairs?

Here is my console:

```
This is the error: null
This is the response: Not Found
```

Here is code for the question:

```
/**
 * Lists the search query results
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function keywordQuery(auth) {
    console.log("This is the auth token" + auth);
    var webmasters = google.webmasters('v3');
    var params = {
        auth: auth,
        siteUrl: 'http://www.test-site.com/',
        resource: {
            'startDate': '2016-11-01',
            'endDate': '2016-11-30',
            'dimensions': ['query']
        }
    };
    var metrics = {};

    var query = webmasters.searchanalytics.query(params, function(err, res){
            console.log('This is the error: ' + err);
            console.log('This is the response: ' + res);
    });
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'webmasters-nodejs-creds.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Webmasters query.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), keywordQuery);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}


/**
 * Lists the search query results
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function keywordQuery(auth) {
    console.log("This is the auth token" + auth);
    var webmasters = google.webmasters('v3');
    var params = {
        auth: auth,
        siteUrl: 'http://www.test-site.com/',
        resource: {
            'startDate': '2016-11-01',
            'endDate': '2016-11-30',
            'dimensions': ['query']
        }
    };
    var metrics = {};

    var query = webmasters.searchanalytics.query(params, function(err, res){
            console.log('This is the error: ' + err);
            console.log('This is the response: ' + res);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I'm in the same situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and got it to work by URI encoding the siteUrl parameter.

```
    siteUrl: encodeURIComponent('http://www.test-site.com')
```

instead of

```
    siteUrl: 'http://www.test-site.com/'
```